# Facebook Graph Api v3.0 How to get User Permissions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Facebook has recently released v3.0 for the Graph Api. Unfortunately all previous versions are deprecated. So a new App must use v3.0.

When I try to get a User Access Token:
[image: Get User Access Token via the Graph Api Explorer]

I Get the following options in previous versions:

[image: V2.11 permission options]

But since v3.0 I only get the following:

[image: V3.0 permission options]

I need manage page and publish permissions, but both are absent. What should be done to extend the permission options?

Comment: i just created a new app without any additional settings and still got all permissions to select...

Comment: That's very strange...

Comment: Could you share more information about the app you made luschn, becuase I have tried several times, but the permissions allways stay the same. Did you do an app review perhaps?

Comment: i just created a completely new app for testing. nothing special. no settings, no review.

Comment: Ok, so my conclusion would be: It has something to do with my own facebook account. Maybe this will get me somewhere.

Comment: It does not make any sense. All my existing apps show all options, so it can't be my account which gives the problem. I've asked a colleague to create a new app and he has exactly the same issue. While both of us have many working already existing apps. Are you sure you are on version 3 for facebook? Maybe there's a difference between countries. We're in the Netherlands.

Comment: i am sure, i created the new app just for this thread. new apps can only use the latest api version anyway. i am in austria..maybe you should file a bug report, including the infos we gathered so far?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Does anyone know why this is the case with v3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since May 1st every new app should be reviewed for using any additional permissions. Once the app is reviewed and approved, you can get the app tokens as before.